# I can't find an example of how to make an HTTP POST request using useEffect hook along with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, http-post, use-effect

Lately, I've been trying to make an HTTP POST request using the useEFfect hook along with axios, but the code returns this error in the console: Error: Request failed with status code 422. The POST request is always successfully made when I make it from the form onSubmit handler. However, when I try to make it from the useEffect hook, it gives that error. Can anybody help me with what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function RandomPost() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    companyName: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInput({ ...input, [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, email, companyName, password } = input;
    axios
      .post(`https://01hire.collaq.com/user/createCompany`, input)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [input]);

  const { name, email, companyName, password } = input;
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" id="name" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Email:
          <input type="text" id="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Company Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            id="companyName"
            value={companyName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password:
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RandomPost;
```

Comment: When do you want the POST request to run? It's running on the initial render cycle when your `input` state values are all empty strings. Server is saying something isn't processable. Do you have access to the API/server to see why it returns 422 status?

Comment: I want to run the POST request when I have inserted all the values in the input fields, and not with the empty strings. Yes I do have access to the API.

Comment: Why POST from the `useEffect` hook? It's going to run and try POSTing after each state update from `handleChange`. You've already the form submit handler. Using an `useEffect` hook doesn't make sense to me here.

Comment: A senior guy told me that you better make all your HTTP requests through the hooks. He told me to make the POST request using the useEffect hook. Otherwise, it was working completely fine with the submit handler.

Comment: Well, I guess in this case you can use a separate "shouldSubmit" state that is toggled true in the `handleSubmit` callback just so you can write an `useEffect` hook with a dependency specific to submit the form data and clear the "shouldSubmit" state. Seems a misuse of an `useEffect` hook, adds unnecessary moving parts, and delays the POST request by at least a render cycle. This suggestion seems misinformed to me. I'd push back on this one or ask for clarification.